# Monospaced font not lining up

Tags: fonts, gui-emacs

On the 2016 MacBook Pro, monospaced fonts are not lining up. It happens to just some buffers and can only be fixed by changing the default font size then changing it back. My font setting is:

```
'(default ((t (:family "Ubuntu Mono" :foundry "nil" :slant normal :weight normal :height 181 :width normal)))))
```

I have the exact same Emacs configuration on two other Macs and never experience this problem.

Comment: Do you see the same thing in other applications, besides Emacs?

Comment: Good question, I don't use mono space in other programs besides git gui. I've never seen them out of pine there.

Comment: when using zoom, the misalignment is fixed. going back to default zoom reintroduces the problem

Comment: this happens on my older 2013 macbook pro as well.. maybe a config issue?